# What should we do with out-of-date answers

Tags: discussion

So @sfdcfox's answer here got flagged because it's not longer accurate:

[Can you select what release your scratch orgs are on](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261331/can-you-select-what-release-your-scratch-orgs-are-on/261332#261332)

Part of me thinks I should just delete it, so that the correct information is readily apparent, but I have two issues with this:

1. It's heavy handed and would remove reputation points for a previously correct answer (not that Mr. Fox would actually hurt from this one!)
2. It assumes that I know the other answer is correct

I'm curious to know what others think should be done in this scenario, trading off fairness/user friendliness for on-going accuracy.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I don't see any action as necessary here. Maybe someone who is well informed can leave a comment explaining why the post is outdated, but that's about the most we should do here.

Comment: Recently a couple of my outdated answers got mass downvoted, not sure if its an effective strategy.

Comment: Agreed. I think what occurred on that example post was great. Someone provided an updated answer and the community has upvoted it more times than the previous answer which was correct at the time. It's easy to read both answers and understand one is more "up-to-date" with the power of time.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves yeah that's more practical. :)

Comment: @PranayJaiswal same happened with me. And this seemed to be an obvious behavior by a particular User as soon as a new answer was posted. I did delete one of my answers which was relevant at the time writing but no more now. But in other scenario, the User down voted one of my answers as soon as new answer was posted, referring to that one because they seemed to disagree with it. And that I didn't have any issue with that but still left my answer in there because it was still relevant.

Comment: @JayantDas exactly for us, it might not make much of a difference, am concerned about newbies, this would feel more hostile and make them stop contributing.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, an outdated answer should be edited. Aside from the reputation loss of deleted answers, there's two main problems.

Accepted answers can't be removed by ordinary means, and nobody but the OP of the question can change the accepted flag, so an inaccurate answer will remain at the top of the list for all time in most cases.

Unaccepted answers with high scores will remain near the top of the list, so they'll be more visible. It's better to edit the answer than to post a new answer that will be at the *bottom* of the list, possibly listed below inaccurate/less-accurate answers.

For an outdated answer edit, I recommend a direct edit for those with reputation, or a comment stating that the answer is outdated. I typically do edit outdated answers that get comments to that effect, and I know our other top users do as well. After all, we want accurate information to be at the top of the page for future visitors.

I don't mind deleting outdated answers, and obviously the reputation loss is insignificant in my case, but I could imagine someone who had just a single +10 answer with, say, 1k rep and just lost 10% of their total rep because of a deletion. It's not fair to wipe out someone else's work if it was fruitful at the time of posting. If you wouldn't do it to a 1k user, you shouldn't do it to a 100k user.

I rarely post answers on questions that have essentially correct or outdated answers. I prefer to edit or comment to get the information updated instead. I don't do what I do for the rep, or the MVP status, or whatever, I do it because I am passionate about Salesforce and when it succeeds, we all succeed to have better, more rewarding lives as a result.

I have deleted that answer, but I would invite people to consider how they would feel if the same thing happened to them.

Comment: Personally I think your answer on that question is still relevant. It shows the history and change of the SF platform. You even said in your answer "currently" and "they are looking into it". On this specific case I feel the answer should have remained but I understand why you deleted it.