# What should we do with out-of-date questions?

Tags: discussion

Inspired by a [What should we do with out-of-date answers](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/what-should-we-do-with-out-of-date-answers) question I wanted to ask what should be done with questions which are out-of-date?

2 years ago [I asked a question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205717/salesforce-dx-how-to-track-custom-objects-changes-in-custom-profiles) which eventually has been flagged by SF team as a bug. It turned out that the bug has been fixed in Winter '20 Patch 7.0.

Should I delete the question? Close it? What's the good practice here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your own questions is perfectly acceptable. Especially if you have anything official in writing from Salesforce (support ticket, known issue, etc.) you should reference that in your post. This sort of information is certainly valuable.